# Hardcoded join Parameter with jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this 3 tables (its an old structure and I can't change it  )

```
Table1      Table2      Table3

ID  (PK)    ID  (PK)    Tab3Nr (PK)
Version(PK) Version(PK) some data
some data   Type(PK)
            Tab3Nr
```

Now I want to make jpa entity from Table1 which has a Table3 attribute.

The Problem is, for Table 1 there can be multiple types of Table2.

The type is nowhere defined in any other table. It has to be set from the program logic

I've tried

```
@OneToOne
@JoinTable(name = "table2", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "version") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "tab3Nr") })
private Table3 tab3;
```

It gives me on Element of Table 3, BUT i can not specify which one.
If there are 2 Elements in Table 2 (type 1 and 2) i get a random? element "Table3"

any ideas?

Comment: no idea what "for Table 1 there can be multiple types of Table2" means. Post an outline of the classes with relation fields

Comment: Table1 to Table2 is one-to-many connection where Table2 represents a weak entity. Then, I presume, Table 2 to table 3 is one-to-one connection (although it can be many to one). This makes T1 to T3 a one to many, so you need to set the hibernate like that.